# Where is Code Analysis in Project properties of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

If I open a .NET 5 project in Visual Studio 2019, I see code analysis as follows.

[image: Code Analysis in Vs 2019]

And now if I open the same project in Visual Studio 2022 Preview, I dont see that any more.

[image: Project Properties in Visual Studio 2022 Preview 3]

What am I missing?

Comment: In addition, if I open a project that has code analysis enabled in VS 2019, that same project in VS 2022 greys-out all my [SuppressMessage] attributes and doesn't give me the original CA warning if I remove them. It doesn't seem like code analysis is even running in VS 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it was a Release Candidate version because in the latest VS2022 the Code Analysis is there:

[image]